# How to fetch image dynamically from database in React to show in the UI?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, redux, material-ui, sequelize.js

I have a React front end with Node backend. I use sequelize for mySQL. In may database there is a "company" table with a column named "logo" where logo(image) is stored. How can I make a URL for img tag to show logo in the UI so that it comes dynamically from database? Here I do it in hard coded approach.

```
return (
        <img className={classes.form}  src={`http://localhost:9100/public/images/logo-1604314988682.png`} />
    )
```

Comment: you mean you've stored logo image as a blob or is it just a logo path?

Comment: Just use a variable in src `src={logo}` where logo is the url

Comment: it is saved in database in logo column with this name "logo-1604314988682.png"

Answer (score 1):

Simply pass your logo path variable in a template literals as given below

```
return (
        <img className={classes.form}  src={logo} />
    )
```